# AWK how to count sum

Tags: awk

input file (FileInput.txt):

`10
20 3
100 5 3
27`

this is my awk script:

`BEGIN{
while((getline line < "FileInput.txt") > 0) {`

`}`

how can i count sum? I tried `sum+=line` however it sums only the first column.

Answer (score 6):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum+=$i} END {print sum}' FileInput.txt
```

Comment: Not strictly required to initialize the sum, but good for maintainability.

Answer (score 5):

The issue with your code is twofold:

1. It does not actually make use of `awk` in the way one usually does. It explicitly loops over the lines of the file in a `BEGIN` block.  This is not the idiomatic way one usually writes `awk` programs, which is to supply (optional) patterns or conditions for blocks to be executed for each input record (line).
2. Since the input consists of records (by default single lines) with more than one number, you would have to treat these records in such a way that the individual numbers are summed up. In other words, you can't add `20 3` to `sum`, but would have to split that up into `20` and `3` first.

---

With GNU `awk` or `mawk`, we may set the record separator, `RS`, to a regular expression that matches any sequence of whitespace characters instead of the default newline.  This make `awk` read the file as a collection of whitespace-separated single field records.  Summing these and printing the sum at the end is then trivial:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' FileInput.txt
168
```

Altenatively,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS = "[[:space:]]+" } { sum += $1 } END { print sum }' FileInput.txt
168
```

Or, you can do some variant on [what Romeo Ninov shows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494988/116858), which is to loop over the fields of each line,

```
$ awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) sum += $i } END { print sum }' file
168
```

Answer (score 2):

You could transform your file so you have one number per line:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < FileInput.txt
```

Then pick a solution from https://stackoverflow.com/q/2702564/7552 to sum them.
For example

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < FileInput.txt | perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { print $sum'
```

Comment: Or something like `|awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'`